# makefile link dir/file name

Tags: makefile

In my project for daily build we storing its library to its version name dir. .
for latest one we are creating symbolic link as a 'LATEST'.
ex.-

```
ls -ltr
drw-r--r-- 1 4096 2010-02-10 16:34 abc7.2.0
drw-r--r-- 1 4096 2010-02-10 16:34 abc7.2.1
drw-r--r-- 1 4096 2010-02-10 16:34 abc7.2.2
drw-r--r-- 1 4096 2010-02-10 16:34 abc7.2.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1    8 2010-02-10 16:34 LATEST -> abc7.2.3
```

Now, In makefile, I want to get dir. name to which LATEST is linking to? 
Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can used shell's functionality to get link values.  In shell you might type

```
$ readlink LATEST
abc7.2.3
```

So in makefile you can just invoke `shell` command to get the actual value.  This will store the link target to value variable.

```
value=$(shell readlink LATEST)
```

Note that it doesn't work relatively to working dir, but, rather, to the directory the symlink is in.

I also reckon a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704003/can-make-check-if-mtime-of-a-dependency-is-different-between-runs-not-just-i) with link-related issues; it may be useful for you.

Comment: use $(realpath) https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html